# Una expresión regular

Tags: html5, regex

Necesito una expresión que divida una frase por palabras, he intentado hacer esto pero solo divide por letras, ayuda
const regex = /[^]/g;

Comment: No hace falta una expresión regular, si usas js entonces basta con usar el método `split`

Comment: El problemita es que no es por uso propio, es más bien un requisito para el proyecto, que se usen expresiones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para separar palabras por espacios se puede usar `[^\s]+`, si queremos que no tenga en cuenta signos de puntuación se incluyen en la expresión regular.

Ejemplo:

```
[^\s.,]+
```

Texto:

```
Quiero ver si separa por palabras, aquí.
Esta es la segunda frase.
```

Resultado:

```
Quiero
ver
si
separa
por
palabras
aquí
Esta
es
la
segunda
frase
```

Puedes probrarlo en https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @Carmen es perfecta. Tendrías que aceptarla. A continuación un pequeño ejemplo de cómo puedes utilizar el método `match()` para conseguir el array de las palabras.

```js
let epigrama = "A la abeja semejante, para que cause placer, el epigrama ha de ser: pequeño, dulce y punzante.";

let rex = /[^\s.,]+/gi;

console.log(
    epigrama.match(rex)
);
```